# Trying to understand NGx-Bootstrap datepicker component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble understanding the docs for the date picker component.

[Date Picker Documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#bs-datepicker-config)

What I understand:

- `[(bsValue)]` should be set to the variable on the controller that I want to fill with a Date object
- `bsDatepicker`is the directive that makes it a date picker

What I don't understand:

- what `#dp=bsDatepicker` is for/does
- `(click)=dp.toggle()` throws an error about the property toggle of undefined being called, but it does work!

I do understand that the spec for this isn't final, but what are these properties and what are they supposed to do?

Comment: `#dp=bsDatepicker` is to set a template variable `dp` to the directive `bsDatepicker`. It basically gives the `db` variable reference to `bsDatePicker` type so it has access to `bsDatePicker` methods and stuffs. Then on button `(click)` event, you assign `dp.toggle()` so that the button will toggle the DatePicker. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: absolutely so. Thank you so much

Comment: @ChauTran please format your comment as an answer, so Chris can mark it as answer

Comment: That's okay I can answer it myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#dp=bsDatepicker` is to set a template variable `dp` to the directive `bsDatepicker`. It basically gives the `db` variable reference to `bsDatePicker` type so it has access to `bsDatePicker` methods and stuffs. Then on button `(click)` event, you assign `dp.toggle()` so that the button will toggle the DatePicker. I hope I am making sense.